# "imap could not open" - What is the path to my Sent folder?

Tags: php, imap-open

I send mails with PhpMailer, but I would like to save the mails in the "Sent" folder in my webmail and Outlook. I have a script but it could not open (imap_open) the file.

What is the correct path?

Here is the script:

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/adminPHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

class Mailer extends PHPMailer {

    public function copyToFolder($folderPath = null) {
        $message = $this->MIMEHeader . $this->MIMEBody;
        $path = "/." . (isset($folderPath) && !is_null($folderPath) ? ".".$folderPath : ""); // Location to save the email
        //$imapStream = imap_open("{" . $this->Host . "}" . $path , $this->Username, $this->Password);
        $imapStream = imap_open("{" . $this->Host . "}" . $path ,"address@mydomain.com", "password");

        imap_append($imapStream, "{" . $this->Host . "}" . $path, $message);
        imap_close($imapStream);
    }
}


$mail = new Mailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
$mail->Host       = "localhost"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "address@mydomain.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password 
$mail->From = "address@mydomain.com";   
$mail->FromName = "Don Joe";            
$mail->AddAddress("to@gmail.com");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                               
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                 
$mail->Subject = "tárgy";
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;


if(!$mail->Send())
{

   echo "Message was not sent <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

   exit;
}else{
    $mail->copyToFolder(); // Will save into inbox
    $mail->copyToFolder("Sent"); // Will save into Sent folder
}
?>
```

My file struction on server:

```
0:/mail/mydomain.com/address/.Sent
```

My website:

```
0:/public_html/mydomain.com (this is root of my website under my domain)
```

My web client configuration:

```
Username:   address@mydomain.com
Password :  password
Incoming server:    mail.mydomain.com
IMAP port: 143
POP3 port: 110
Outgoing server:    mail.mydomain.com
SMTP port: 26
```

Error message:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream
>
> Warning: imap_append() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>
> Warning: imap_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 0):

you may list your all folder names of your mailbox (full folder names), most mail servers have the name for the sent folder INBOX.Sent or INBOX.SentItems etc. You should provide the fullname.